# Is is possible to host a ASP.NET Core 2 Web API NET Core 2 application in Windows Service targeting

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a ASP.NET Core Web Web Api application targeting `netcoreapp2.0`.

I want to host the Kestrel server inside a Windows Service.

The examples I've seen like this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?tabs=aspnetcore2x are for Core Web API running on .NET Framework 4.6.1.

How can I host my application in a Windows Service but still target `netcoreapp2.0`?

Comment: I think you must target .NET Framework for that. In the link you provide, one of the prerequisites is: "The app must run on the .NET Framework runtime. In the .csproj file, specify appropriate values for TargetFramework and RuntimeIdentifier.(...)"

Comment: Yes, I saw that prerequisite. But I'm hoping there is another way

Comment: You can't, but you can isolate the Windows Service code to a separate Framework-targeted project and keep the rest netstandard or Core. See [this](https://stackify.com/creating-net-core-windows-services/) for an example.

Comment: That article is very vague, no source code, and I don't see how referencing a shared library from a windows service and a web api helps! The service can call the library, but the library can't call the web api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to host a .Net Core 2 Kestrel server inside a Windows service but you have to use the nssm.  Nssm is a tool that makes it easy to turn a .net core application in to a service.

It even allows you to send a `CTRL-C` message from the service when it shuts down. This is important because Core doesn't currently support the traditional `OnStart` and `OnStop` messages from  Windows services.

Point nssm toward a `batch` or `cmd` file that starts your application. All you need for that is a one liner like -

```
dotnet myApplication.dll
```

Nssm will add that to your Windows services.

See [Hosting a .NET Core 2 Kestrel Server in a Windows Service](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2018/04/hosting-a-net-core-2-kestrel-server-in-a-windows-service/) for full details.

Comment: Is that your own blog you are linking to?

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)