# Net core 2.0 install windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-core-2.0, nuget-package

After installing nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices 2.0 It is not working because this package was created only for 4.6.1

I was install 2.1.0-preview2-final.

Ok, with `host.RunAsService()` it is compiling but not working when I start it via cmd 
And I have this message:

> Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.  A Windows
>   Service must first be installed and then started with the
>   ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START
>   command.

How to install my project as a Windows Service?

This post [Is is possible to host a ASP.NET Core 2 Web API NET Core 2 application in Windows Service targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457156/is-is-possible-to-host-a-asp-net-core-2-web-api-net-core-2-application-in-window) do not helps me.

And it is 3rd part tool, it is overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

I was update net core to 2.1, then I am publish my app as a portable for x86.
After publish in path was a exe!!!
Then I was start cmd line

```
SC create [Name] binpath="[pathtoexe\app.exe]"
```

And then I started like ordinary windows service.

PROFIT!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell to install your windows service. Just open an elevated powershell prompt, cd into the folder where your .net core service executable is, and type:

```
sc.exe create "My Service" binPath= (Resolve-Path .\MyService.exe)
```

I always make a self-contained deployment package for my .net core services, so I just zip the published folder, copy it to the target server, unzip it, then install it as above. After this `My Service` service should show up in the Services MMC SnapIn, from where you can start it, or staying in PowerShell you can start it by:

```
Start-Service -Name "My Service"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It can be only dll.
Not changing 4.6 framework in project file.
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices was compiling without errors and warnings

Comment: I like the Resolve-Path way of doing it, but you need quotes around the parenthesis, not the service name.